# Autoit get Excel values

Tags: excel, autoit

I'm getting values from Excel to Autoit script. Autoit script works independently and not driven by Excel vba or etc. Everything works perfect but Excel values are changing from time to time by vba and here problems starts. Autoit get values from excel every 500 msc but cannot get values from excel while vba updates values and this cause Autoit error and terminate script execution. I've tried to handle autoit error but no luck. The goal I want to met is when script fail into error sleep it for a sec and then retry. This is my script

```
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include "WinHttp.au3"
#include <Date.au3>


; Attach to the first Workbook where the file name matches
Local $sWorkbook = "Ant_5.xlsm"
$oWorkbook = _Excel_BookAttach($sWorkbook, "filename")
If @error Then
   ConsoleWrite("Error attaching to '" & $sWorkbook & "'." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
Endif


Func getData()
   $LastRow = $oWorkbook.Worksheets("Selector").UsedRange.Rows.Count
   $mydata = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, "Selector", "A1:P" & $LastRow)
   $i=0
   $oHTTP = ObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   For $i = 2 To $LastRow-1
      if $mydata[$i][0]<>"" Then
            $cDate=$mydata[$i][0]
            $cTime=$mydata[$i][1]
            $cRule=$mydata[$i][5]
            ConsoleWrite($cRule& @CRLF)
      EndIf
   Next
EndFunc


getData()
```

I simulate error by selecting a cell in Excel. After this Autoit fails but I need to make it retry after a wile until it get data.

Comment: What are you doing with vba? Maybe do this with Autoit aswell. Another option would be copy the file and then run your script on the copy where no vba code is running.

Comment: I agree with using AutoIt to replace your VBA. If you can't, however, you'll need to let us know what AutoIt error you're getting when it quits. I'm guessing that _Excel_RangeRead doesn't return data and you attempt to get the value from the invalid array